# JS XHR JSON payload upload progress

Tags: javascript, upload, xmlhttprequest

Any way to get the progress while uploading a big JSON payload string using XHR?

in my code, it only prints 100% once it is completed, even the json payload size = 30MB

```
let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
        xmlhttp.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.lengthComputable); // false
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log((Math.round(percentComplete * 100) + "%"));
            }
        }, false);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (event) => {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status <= 299) {
                let res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                if (typeof this.options.onVideoGetsUploaded === "function") {
                    console.log('success')
                }
            } else if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 400 && xmlhttp.status <= 550) {
                //error while uploading
                console.log(xmlhttp.statusText)
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", this.options.uploadEndPoint, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
            data: base64data
        }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through some old code where I’ve done this. For uploading I did this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// before opening your request
request.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    // progress in % is: Number(e.loaded / e.total * 100)
};

// open and send request
```

It seems weird and I remember spending some hours trying to figure this one out. Maybe you could also do:

```
request.upload.addEventListener(“progress”, callback())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set content-length header in you request, then the evt.lengthComputable can be true.

Comment: If you set the content length, you will get ```Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"```